# Return Multiple Values C#

Tags: c#, class, return

I have written a separate class that holds the permissions of my website. I make calls to this class in every class I have. I am having trouble bringing back the values from my permissions class. I will show you what I have below:

Permissions Class

```
public class Permissions
{
     public static string selectedNumber = "";
     public static string selectedName= "";
     public static string selectedLocation= "";

     public Info SetInfo(string selectedValue)
    {           
        string selectInfo = "SELECT [Num] AS 'Number', [Name] AS 'Name', CONVERT(nvarchar(50),RTRIM(b.Num])) + ' - ' + CONVERT(nvarchar(50),b.Name) AS 'Location' "
            + "FROM [TBL_Info] a "
            + "left join [TBL_Where] b on (a.[ID] = b.[ID]) "
            + "WHERE a.ID = @ID";

        sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(selectInfo, sqlConn);
        sqlConn.Open();

        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", selectedValue);

        SqlDataReader rdrInfo = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();

        if (rdrInfo.HasRows)
        {
            rdrInfo.Read();

            selectedNumber = rdrInfo .GetSqlString(rdrInfo .GetOrdinal("Number")).ToString();
            selectedName= rdrInfo .GetSqlString(rdrInfo .GetOrdinal("Name")).ToString();
            selectedLocation = rdrInfo .GetSqlString(rdrInfo .GetOrdinal("Location")).ToString();
        }
        sqlCmd.Connection.Close();

        return new Info()
        {
           number= selectedNumber, 
           name= selectedName,
           location= selectedLocation

        };
    }

    public class Info
    {
        public String number{ get; set; }
        public String name{ get; set; }
        public String location{ get; set; }
    }
}
```

And I am currently trying to call it in another class like this:

```
Classes.Permissions permission = new Classes.Permissions();
permission.SetInfo(selectedUserValue);
```

The end product is that I set textboxes in the class I am trying to make the call from with the 3 return values from `permission.SetInfo()`

Currently I am not able to get anything returned.... I know I am doing something wrong, clearly. So can someone please give me some advice on how to achieve this?

Comment: You are not saving object which you are returning `var info = permission.SetInfo(selectedUserValue);` After that you can use `info` variable

Comment: Right, I see that... but how will I return the 3 objects? In a list?

Comment: You should open the sql connection in a `using` block so it always gets closed.

Comment: If you want to return several `Info` objects, then collection (list/array etc) is an option. If each of these objects have separate meaning then consider to create class with three properties of type `Info` with appropriate names, and return that object

Comment: So lets get this right: your function that GETs some info is actually called `SetInfo`?  Do you see what is wrong with that?

Comment: LOL. Lets get this right, your username is JK. So I am assuming you are kidding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other than some stylistic things I have issue with, your code looks like it should work (as long as you have data in your database).  To return multiple values from a method, create a new object (ie `Info`) that defines the things to be returned.

So, you should be able to write something like:

```
Textbox txtBox;

var info = new Classes.Permissions().SetInfo(SelectedUserValue);

txtBox.Text = 
       info.number ?? "<null>" + " " + 
       info.name ?? "<null> + " " + 
       info.location ?? "<null>'
```

Note that I used the null coalescing operator (`??`) as `SetInfo` could return an instance of `Info`, where all members are `null` if no rows are returned from your database query.

By the way, the other way to return multiple values from a method is to use `out` parameters:

```
Textbox txtBox;
string number;
string name;
string location;

new Classes.Permissions().SetInfo(SelectedUserValue, out number, out name, out location);
```

And then your `SetInfo` would look like:

```
public void SetInfo(string SeelctedUserValue, 
     out string number, out string name, out string location)
{
    //assign values to number,name and location
}
```

---

To return **multiple** instances of the same object, than your method should return

1. an `IEnumerable` (ie a `List` or `Array`),
2. a `Tuple<>`,
3. a container object.

For example, if you know you are going to return exactly three, you might want to have your method return `Tuple<Info,Info,Info>`:

```
public Tuple<Info, Info, Info> SetInfo(string SeelctedUserValue)
{
   //query db
   return new Tuple<Info, Info, Info>(
     new Info{ number = "number", name = "name", location="location},
     new Info{ number = "number", name = "name", location="location},
     new Info{ number = "number", name = "name", location="location});         
}
```

Comment: The out parameters looks a little easier... too

Comment: There's several ways to do what you are trying to do.  You'll have to decide which is easiest for your situation and environment.

Comment: I have both my initial way and parameters working. Will decide what is best for me. Thank you very much